# How do I redirect 80 to 443 using NGINX and why does it seem to use both server blocks?

Tags: nginx

I have the following config for my NGINX

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       443 ssl default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        include      snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include      snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        server_name  _;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        if ($scheme = http) {
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

But then when the following happens...

```bash
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-45-134 nginx]$ curl https://secondave.net --insecure
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.22.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine but doesn't redirect if I comment out `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`.

What am I missing how do I have both?

I also tried to do this...

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-45-134 next-site]$ curl -L https://secondave.net --insecure
curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

Another weird thing is the same seems to happen with proxy

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       443 ssl default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        include      snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include      snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        server_name  _;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }      
}
```

works but

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       443 ssl default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        include      snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include      snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        server_name  _;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
    }     
}
```

Doesn't properly proxy

Comment: why do you want to comment that out? note that when you use curl, it won't automatically follow redirects unless you tell it to. https://reqbin.com/req/c-bvijc9he/curl-follow-redirect

Comment: I don't want to comment it out I have to comment it out to get it to work. I want it to redirect 80 without redirecting 443 as well. I was just pointing out it works without the redirect.

Comment: Updated to add what happens if I use the redirect flag. This shows that it is actually redirecting back in a loop

Comment: If you "comment out return 301" why would it redirect I don't see any other rule to do that? Also, maybe there is something else set in `/etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf` other config files?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is that's causing the loop (for HTTPS traffic to also get redirected again to HTTP and following the 301 return rule) you can prevent it by adding an `if` to the rule:

```
if ($scheme = http) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Weird you would think this would be foolproof but it is still trying to redirect

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line in the SSL server block is still passing the request to the insecure URL.

Change `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;`

To `proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;`